# Determine if Ethernet is plugged/unplugged [batch code]

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a little script for a laptop and I want to make it better.

I want the batch to determine if the Ethernet connection is plugged or not.

If Ethernet is plugged, I would like to make it connect via rasdial and to ping. If PC receives response from ping, then to show "Connection established successfully". If no response from ping, then "Connection failed".

If Ethernet is unplugged, just to show "No wired connection".

Here's current code:

```
@echo off

rasdial <Dialup_connection_name> <User> <Pass>

ping -n 1 -w 3000 www.google.com >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  cls
  msg * Connection failed
  exit
)

cls
msg * Connection established successfully
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
netsh interface show interface name="LAN-Verbindung" |find "Verbindungsstatus" |find "Verbunden">nul && echo connected || echo not connected
```

(this works on a german windows; you have to localize it)

to look nicer in the batchfile, you can write it like this:

```
netsh interface show interface name="LAN-Verbindung" ^
 |find "Verbindungsstatus" ^
 |find "Verbunden">nul ^
   && echo connected ^
   || echo not connected
```

Answer (score 2):

I made it! Here's the code if anybody wants it! :D

```
@echo off

netsh interface show interface name="Ethernet" ^
 |find "Connected">nul ^
   && goto connection ^
   || goto unplugged

:connection
rasdial <Dialup_connection_name> <User> <Pass>
ping -n 1 -w 3000 www.google.com >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  cls
  msg * Connection failed!
  exit
)
cls
msg * Connection established successfully!
exit

:unplugged
cls
msg * No wired connection!
exit
```

Comment: just one hint: labels with spaces are not allowed. `goto unplugged connection` jumps to label `unplugged` and ignores `connection`. At the target side the label is `:unplugged` and `connection` is also ignored.

Comment: Please mark one of those answers as accepted, so that everyone can see, that your problem is solved.