# Catch a moment when Ethernet is plugged in and out

Tags: c++, winapi, networking, ethernet

I need some way to determine when Ethernet connetction is established or disabled.
I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439971/determine-if-ethernet-is-plugged-unplugged-batch-code) how to check it with batch but I'd prefer to use Winapi and friends.

Is there sort of notification to achieve this? If not is there some api to check if connection established now (I could check it periodically)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at:

- [`NotifyAddrChange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366329.aspx) and [`NotifyIpInterfaceChange()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814450.aspx).  They give you events when interface IP addresses change.
- [Network Awareness](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264321.aspx), which gives you events when networks are added/removed, change status, etc.